# Multiple Permalinks for custom post type post

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, url-rewriting

is there a way to have multiple permalinks for a custom post type post?

For example:

The normal permalink url is called:

```
https://www.example.com/test-subject/test-title
```

I also want the post is reachable under the following urls:

```
https://www.example.com/test-subject/post_id

https://www.example.com/ts/post_id
```

I know that I can manual add in the .htaccess, but I add the post inside my plugin. So what is the best method to add these urls to a post and make them accessable?

I need some suggestions, not code solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible using [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/), something along the lines of

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'test-subject/(\d+)/?',
    'index.php?post_type=CPT_slug&post_id=$matches[1]'
);
add_rewrite_rule(
    'ts/(\d+)/?',
    'index.php?post_type=CPT_slug&post_id=$matches[1]'
);
```

It might be a bit trickier though, since `test-subject/test-title` and `test-subject/post_id` are quite similar. Adding the `post_id`-rule with the 3rd argument as `'top'` might help.

Comment: I added in the main file of my plugin . function add_my_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'test-subject/(\d+)/?',
        'index.php?post_type=real_estate&page_id=$matches[1]'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'add_my_rule'); is not working

Comment: It works, redirects to a different page as the original. Maybe there is a solution with a specific meta_key & meta_value?

Comment: You need to flush the rewrite rules after first adding the code. I don't have much time right now to help further, maybe `page_id` is the wrong key (although it worked in my small test)?

Comment: OK, worked. I used index.php?p=post_id

Comment: @yfain Thanks for the updated, I changed my answer so other people will have the correct answer straight away