# Using meta_key & meta_value in add_rewrite_rule

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

as a plus to my question here: [Multiple Permalinks for custom post type post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307660/multiple-permalinks-for-custom-post-type-post)

I have an additional question. I make a new question because the old one is answered correctly.

My Code is the following:

```
function add_my_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'test-subject/(\d+)/?',
        'index.php?p=$matches[1]', 'top'
    );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'add_my_rule');
```

This code is placed in my index file in my plugin.

The thing is now: We have an `meta_key` called `test_id`. So I want to make a link like `https://www.example.com/test-subject/1`. In this link `1` is not the post id it is the `test_id` from the `meta_key` of a post. So I want to redirect to the post, which have the right meta_key test_id. Some suggestions?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should definitely not be calling `flush_rewrite_rules()` on `init`. Rules should be flushed once when they change. [The documentation has examples of how to do this correctly](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules).

Comment: Some suggestions?